# mod_rewrite rules

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, directory

I'm trying to get the data after the URL and sent back to the home page. I have had errors in the .htaccess file on one server so I am trying it out on another server.

The links down the side of `http://www.newbiemoneymakers.com/bank/` should do directly to `http://www.newbiemoneymakers.com/bank/index.php` where I then get the title.

My .htaccess file says:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^http://www.newbiemoneymakers.com/bank/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?title=$1 [L]
```

My index page says:

```
<?php

    include('includes/functions.php');

    $activeTab = "navhome"; 
    $sent = false;

    $title = (isset($_GET['title']))? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['title']) : 'Home';    
    $title = str_replace('-',' ', $title);

    if($title != '') {  

        $sql = "SELECT * 
                FROM contents 
                WHERE name LIKE '%$title%'
                LIMIT 1";

        $result = @mysql_query($sql);       
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);      
    }

    //Set page title
    $pagetitle = (isset($row['name']) && $title != 'Home')? ucwords($row['name']) : "Bank Charges";
?>
```

But when I click on any of the links (e.g. `http://www.newbiemoneymakers.com/bank/bank-charges-refund/`) it gives me a 404 page!

Do you know where I am going wrong?

Ian

Answer (score 2):

The pattern of a `RewriteRule` is just tested agains the URI path (in .htaccess files without the contextual per-directory prefix, so in the root directory without the leading `/`).

So this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^bank/([^/.]+)/?$ bank/index.php?title=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I still cannot get it to work! my .htaccess file now says:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^bank/([^/.]+)/?$ bank/index.php?title=$1 [L]

I have uploaded it to the directory and to the root directory but still getting a 404!

Comment: My rule was intended for the .htaccess in your root directory. And it works for me. Are you sure mod_rewrite is enabled?

Comment: Ye, i asked the hosting if it was installed and enabled!

Comment: Hm. Did you try a simpler rule to proof that? Somthing like `RewriteRule ^ http://example.com [L,R]`

Comment: I have tested that mod_rewrite is working! I did a little exaple where one page directs to another and it works! I still cant get the main problem working tho!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have just fixed it! 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?title=$1 [L]

Comment: So you wanted a rule for your bank directory? You should have said that.